# Attempting to write data from one sheet to Another

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have this code. I want to make it iterative until there is no more data on the temp sheet.

I have a temporary workbook with a year of information that I want to have written to multiple excel files in a weeks worth of data. What I am attempting to do is copy from the temporary workbook "WorkingJan4newexperemental" to an active workbook (which changes since I am writing to multiple workbooks) but the sheet in the active workbook will always be "Data". I will be copying range "B6:I677." After it is copied I'd like the range "B6:I677" to be deleted from the temporary workbook so I can open another work book and run the Macro again. Currently I have.

```
Sub CutPasteSaveRepeat()
'
' CutPasteSaveRepeat Macro
'

'
    Windows("WorkingJan4newexperemental.xlsm").Activate
    Range("B6:I677").Select
    Range("I677").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("2013W29.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "\\Webserver\umc\091_AU20100226\210_Comments\Electricity\Capital Hall\Zip\2013W30.xlsm" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    Windows("WorkingJan4newexperemental.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("2013W30.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "\\Webserver\umc\091_AU20100226\210_Comments\Electricity\Capital Hall\Zip\2013W31.xlsm" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    Windows("WorkingJan4newexperemental.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("2013W31.xlsm").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
      ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "\\Webserver\umc\091_AU20100226\210_Comments\Electricity\Capital Hall\Zip\2013W32.xlsm" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    Windows("WorkingJan4newexperemental.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("2013W32.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Windows("WorkingJan4newexperemental.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Windows("2013W33.xlsm").Activate
      ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "\\Webserver\umc\091_AU20100226\210_Comments\Electricity\Capital Hall\Zip\2013W33.xlsm" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    Windows("WorkingJan4newexperemental.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("2013W34.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does the name of the workbooks have a pattern? (Like "Working<month>newexperimental.xlsx")

Comment: 2013W21 -> 2013W32 -? 2013W33 etc.

Comment: if you are deleting `B6:I677` in the temp workbook, what data range do you want to select to copy into the next workbook that you open? Perhaps, more precisely, what is the correlation between the data that needs to get copied from the temp workbook to whichever workbook is open?

Comment: Precisely B6:I677 again. I have long stream of data, months worth that I am breaking down into worksheets consisting of 1 week or 672 data points. 7 days times * 24 hours * 4 for 15 minute breakdowns. So that will allow me to open the files and transfer the data that belongs in each file.

Comment: So, where exactly are you stuck? Or where do you need help? And what is the name of the temp workbook that has all the data to be copied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is:

1. Copy a range from a workbook
2. Paste that range to another workbook
3. Delete the original range and shift all the cells bellow it up
4. Keep doing this until you've copied all of the data in the original sheet

Here's a sub that should get you started:

```
Sub copypasteiterate()

        Dim expBook As Workbook, thisBook As Workbook
        Dim counter As Integer
        Dim sheetend As Boolean

        Set thisBook = ActiveWorkbook

        counter = 1
        Do While sheetend = False

            If Range("A1").Value = "" Then sheetend = True

            'Open a new book and copy and paste the range into it

            Set expBook = Workbooks.Add
            thisBook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B2").Copy
            expBook.ActiveSheet.Paste

            'Save under some name which includes the counter

            expBook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\test\data" & counter & ".xlsx"
            counter = counter + 1

            'Delete the original range and shift up

            ThisWorkbook.Activate
            Range("A1:B2").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Loop

 End Sub
```

I used A1:B2 as my range but you could use whatever you need to use. Same goes for the names of the files. I've also assumed that there aren't any blanks in your data. If there are you might need a more sophisticated way of checking if all the data has been copied.

Comment: 'Set counter to week number'
        counter = 18
        Do While sheetend = False

            If Range("B6").Value = "" Then sheetend = True
   
            Set expBook = "2013W18.xlsx" 'I want to start with this file.       thisBook.ActiveSheet.Range("B6:I677").Copy
            expBook.ActiveSheet.Paste
            
        expBook.SaveAs Filename:= _        "\\Webserver\umc\091_AU20100226\210_Comments\Electricity\Capital Hall\Zip\2013W" & counter & ".xlsx"
            '''expBook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\test\data" & counter & ".xlsx"
            counter = counter + 1

Comment: Can I add the counter to a already started count. I will be starting with 2013W18

Comment: If you can figure out how use Windows("2013W18.xlsm").Activate = expBook, I think that would do it!